# Virtualbox not starting after downgrading kernel on my laptop

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, xubuntu, downgrade

I was having graphics issues with my laptop on Xubuntu 18.04LTS with kernel 4.15.0-58-generic, so i downgraded to 3.19.0-59-generic. That fixed the graphics issues, but now virtualbox won't start Virtual machines. it complains about virtualbox-DKMS modules not being loaded and tells me to install virtualbox-dkms and then run modprobe to load it. I did that but it's not compiling for kernel 3.19.0-59-generic.

throws an error about

```
DKMS kernel package linux-headers-3.19.0-59-generic not supported
```

wnen trying to install virtualbox-dkms. I am running virtualbox 5.2 at the moment. is there an older version i need to install or is there any way to keep using 5.2 with this kernel?

Running an ati radeon X1300... doesn't seem to like the radeonDrivers that come with ubuntu.

Comment: Unable to find a Virtualbox reference to kernels it supports; and it's been requested before. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17055

Comment: Ended up reverting to the kernel that caused my gpu problems and editing /etc/default/grub to boot with radeon.modeset=1. ALL is working with the problem kernel. graphics, virtualbox, everything. graphics confirmed by a quick round of brutal doom in wine. and lspci `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515/M52 [Mobility Radeon X1300]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
   
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon`

Comment: Excellent! Answer your own question and accept it, so others can benefit from your experience!